# Add standard error bar to my line graph in R

Tags: r, graph, line, standards

I have a bar graph that I would like to add standard deviation.

My graph equation is:

```
curve((exp(1.54 + -0.59*x) )/ (1+ exp (1.54- 0.59*x)), 0,30, ylab = "occupancy", xlab = "Livestock (%)", ylim=c(0,1))
```

I would like to add two extra lines representing Standard deviation to the graph (`SD=  (exp(0.98-0.55*x) )/ (1+ exp (0.98- 0.55*x)`)

I have tried using the function `errbar` but have been unsuccessful.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the equation for the second line representing SD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the plot with `curve`:

```
curve((exp(1.54 - 0.59 * x) )/ (1 + exp (1.54 - 0.59 * x)), 0, 30, 
      ylab = "occupancy", xlab = "Livestock (%)", ylim = c(0, 1))
```

Then, you can use `curve` with the argument `add = TRUE` to add a line to the existing plot:

```
curve((exp(0.98 - 0.55 * x)) / (1 + exp(0.98 - 0.55 * x)), 
      add = TRUE, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]